# Second formbuilder include fields of first formbuilder

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Related to my previous post [Call to a member function addPaiementType() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236823/call-to-a-member-function-addpaiementtype-on-null), if I have two distinct form:

```
$form = $app['manager.form']
    ->addDuree()
    ->addPaiementType()
    ->addTermsAccepted()
    ->getForm();

$formcb = $app['manager.form']
    ->addFirstname()
    ->addLastname()
    ->addNumero()
    ->addMonth()
    ->addYear()
    ->addCryptogramme()
    ->getForm();
```

The render of the second form include the fields of the form declared before it... It should not, because I have declared two distinct object Form.

Don't understand why the second form include the fields of the first one.

But this is working:

```
//$form = $app['manager.form']
$f1 = new Form($app);
$form = $f1
    ->addDuree()
    ->addPaiementType()
    ->addTermsAccepted()
    ->getForm();

//$formcb = $app['manager.form']
$f2 = new Form($app);
$formcb = $f2
    ->addFirstname()
    ->addLastname()
    ->addNumero()
    ->addMonth()
    ->addYear()
    ->addCryptogramme()
    ->getForm();
```

For me, it is exactly the same thing, but it seems not...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change `$app['manager.form']` on calling `addXXX` methods, not copy.

If want to keep `$app['manager.form']` as template for other forms protect callback that returns object to get callback itself on getting `manager.form` from application.

```
$app['manager.form'] = $app->protect(function() use ($app) {
    return new Form($app);
});

$form = $app['manager.form']();
$form = $form
    ->addDuree()
    ->addPaiementType()
    ->addTermsAccepted()
    ->getForm();

$formcb = $app['manager.form']();
$formcb = $formcb
    ->addFirstname()
    ->addLastname()
    ->addNumero()
    ->addMonth()
    ->addYear()
    ->addCryptogramme()
    ->getForm();
```